# snakemake: Ambiguous rule not detected?

Tags: exception, snakemake

The following Snakefile fails with `AmbiguousRuleException`:

```
library_id = ['S1']
run_id = ['R1']

samples = dict(zip(library_id, run_id))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{library_id}.bam', library_id= library_id),

rule bwa:
    output:
        '{run_id}.bam',

rule merge_bam:
    input:
        lambda wc: '%s.bam' % samples[wc.library_id],
    output:
        '{library_id}.bam',
```

Gives:

```
    AmbiguousRuleException:
    Rules bwa and merge_bam are ambiguous for the file S1.bam.
    Consider starting rule output with a unique prefix, constrain your wildcards, or use the ruleorder directive.
    Wildcards:
        bwa: run_id=S1
        merge_bam: library_id=S1
    Expected input files:
        bwa: 
        merge_bam: R1.bamExpected output files:
        bwa: S1.bam
        merge_bam: S1.bam
```

That's expected and it's ok. However, if `library_id` and `run_id` have **the same** value the ambiguity is not detected and only the first rule is executed:

```
library_id = ['S1']
run_id = ['S1'] # Same as library_id!

samples = dict(zip(library_id, run_id))

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{library_id}.bam', library_id= library_id),

rule bwa:
    output:
        '{run_id}.bam',

rule merge_bam:
    input:
        lambda wc: '%s.bam' % samples[wc.library_id],
    output:
        '{library_id}.bam',
```

Dry-run execution:

```
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   bwa
    2

[Mon Aug 23 11:27:39 2021]
localrule bwa:
    output: S1.bam
    jobid: 1
    wildcards: run_id=S1

[Mon Aug 23 11:27:39 2021]
localrule all:
    input: S1.bam
    jobid: 0

Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   bwa
    2
This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? The second example should give `AmbiguousRuleException` just like the first and it's even more obvious.

This is with snakemake 6.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Snakemake performs some checks for cycles and jobs with the same input and output file(s) are removed from consideration during DAG creation. In your working case, the job from the `merge_bam` rule has the same input/output file (`S1.bam`) so it is not considered in the DAG and their is no ambiguity when satisfying the input of the `all` rule.

### Details

Snakemake starts with the final target file (in this case `S1.bam`) and works backward to find parameterized rules (jobs) that can be executed to create the target file from existing input files. To do this, it recursively calls `snakemake/dag.py::DAG.update()` and `snakemake/dag.py::DAG.update_()` to construct the DAG from the initial target file(s). `DAG.update()` has the [following check](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/7f54c391f2821655ed168bcdafad6d07b96fcec7/snakemake/dag.py#L740-L742) to remove jobs from consideration if they produce the same output file that they require for input:

```python
if file in job.input:
    cycles.append(job)
    continue
```

E.g. if the target file is also the candidate job's input file, skip this candidate job.

In your working case, the job from the `merge_bam` rule is considered as a candidate for producing the `S1.bam` file requested by the `all` rule. However, the `merge_bam` job also requests `S1.bam` for it's own input, so it fails the above check for cycles. Consequently, it is not considered a producer for the `S1.bam` file requested by the `all` rule, leaving only the `bwa` job.

In the exception case, the `merge_bam` rule outputs `S1.bam` but asks for `R1.bam` as input, so it passes the cycle check and is considered a potential producer of the `S1.bam` file requested by the `all` rule. Since both `merge_bam` and `bwa` can produce `S1.bam` (and there is no ruleorder defined) an `AmbiguousRuleException` is thrown.

### Conclusions

The mixing of a cyclic DAG and ambiguous rules causes this unintuitive behavior. Snakemake doesn't aim to find all possible rule ambiguities, so I would not necessarily say that this is a bug.